# Calculate the travel time from locations to the closest N points

Tags: qgis, r, point, point-in-polygon, isochrone

I  want to calculate the travel time (based on walking time) from locations to the closest N points of another dataset. Then I want to create a hull around those N closest points per location

Is this possible? How can this be done?

The software does not really matter; I have access to QGIS, FME, ArcGIS, R, python; any other software is fine with me. However, I do not know where to start.

Comment: Isochrones are about time. Isodistances are about travel distance. What do you *really* want to do, without using the term "isochrone"?

Comment: I have different locations (where to vote) and I want to know which are the closest 1000 voters (based on time). And then I want to create a polygon based on the points.

Comment: So you want to calculate the travel time from locations to the closest N points of another dataset. And you also want to create a hull around those N closest points per location.

Comment: Exactly, that is it :)

Comment: Then update your question accordingly ;)

Comment: That is done. Thanks

Comment: The key to this is good network data (in your case roads/paths) and a clean topology. What network data do you have?

Answer (score -1):

With Qgis and ArcGIS, you can use network analyst tools. Use the Origin Destination Matrixes from [here](https://root676.github.io/)

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like that in FME Workbench. Here you have step-by-step instruction at [knowledge.safe.com](https://knowledge.safe.com/articles/30048/creating-time-and-distance-isolines-using-the-netw.html): It probably would need some modification for your purpose.